# How to replace a space in a URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

These are the 2 relevant lines from a function written in JavaScript:

```
var v_depttime = document.getElementById("EDDepttime").value ;
url = url+"?select_bno="+v_busno+"&select_depttime="+v_depttime ;
```

It sends the `select_depttime` as `2010-01-24 14:30:00`
and I want it to be an URL encoded string like `2010-01-24%2014:30:00`

How is it done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use encodeURIComponent:

```
url = url +
  "?select_bno=" + encodeURIComponent(v_busno) +
  "&select_depttime=" + encodeURIComponent(v_depttime);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).